# How to add an image at the position of cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext, imageview

[image]I'm working on an android app which is used for taking notes. And note can can contain an image  along-with text. I want to add the image at the current location of cursor. Is it feasible in android?

See i want something like this

Comment: can you able to get the location of cursor?

Comment: that would be end of line i guess

Comment: you should be able to get the ending coordinated of the cusror point. then you can set setX() and setY() to your imageview.

Comment: i do not have any issue with single image but user can add multiple images

Comment: you have  methods called getLeft() and getRight()  of a view .you can use these to get your goal.

Comment: see here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 2):

```
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ImageSpan imgSpan = new ImageSpan(this, b);
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString("xccsxcsdcdscds");
    spanString.setSpan(imgSpan, 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv_show.setText(spanString);
    tv_show.append("22222");
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: SpannableString  Can handle your text.setSpan() can put your image into your text any position,the first parameter is image,two parameter is start position of the image,three parameter is end position .Then put the text into textview.